# terraform 1.0.6 cannot find providers if I can change directory

Tags: terraform

If I run `terraform -version` from the directory that I ran `terraform init`, terraform correctly finds the plugins.

But if I run `terraform -version` from any other directory, terraform does NOT find any provider plugins.

My ~/.terraformrc file looks like this:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/.terraform/providers"
    include = ["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/*"]
  }
}
```

Inside that directory, I have the aws provider binary (it was placed there by `terraform init`, so I know the directory structure is correct:

`/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.55.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v3.55.0_x5`

When I `cd` to `/`, terraform correctly finds the provider:

```
# terraform -version
Terraform v1.0.6
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.55.0
```

But if I cd to /tmp, terraform does NOT find the provider:

```
/tmp # terraform -version
Terraform v1.0.6
on linux_amd64
```

So that tells me there is something not right with the `.terraformrc` file.

If I run that with TRACE, it doesn't say much:

```
2021-09-08T03:01:30.336Z [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /root/.terraformrc
2021-09-08T03:01:30.336Z [INFO]  Loading CLI configuration from /root/.terraformrc
2021-09-08T03:01:30.336Z [DEBUG] Explicit provider installation configuration is set
2021-09-08T03:01:30.336Z [TRACE] Selected provider installation method cliconfig.ProviderInstallationFilesystemMirror("/.terraform/providers") with includes [registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/*] and excludes []
2021-09-08T03:01:30.337Z [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"version", "-version"}
Terraform v1.0.6
on linux_amd64
```

How can I tell terraform to look in `/.terraform/providers" for all of it's providers?

Comment: You actually placed your `"/.terraform/providers"` in the root of your filesystem, not in your home user folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your investigations here you are confusing two different concepts for Terraform provider installation: a local filesystem mirror (which you've configured in your CLI configuration), and your current working directory's *provider cache* (which is where `terraform init` installs the providers for the current working directory).

A local filesystem mirror happens to support a similar directory structure to a provider cache directory, and so what you've achieved by running Terraform in the root directory is to trick Terraform into thinking that your local mirror *is* the local cache directory for that working directory. It doesn't work anywhere else because in that case these two separate directories are truly separate, which is the expected way to use Terraform.

The other relevant thing to know in what you tried here is that `terraform version` will only show providers that are already installed and activated by `terraform init`. Again, because you tricked Terraform into treating your filesystem mirror as the local cache directory it happened to find the required `hashicorp/aws` plugin there, but when you ran it elsewhere there was no local cache directory and so it returned nothing.

You mentioned that your goal is to have Terraform look for providers only in your local filesystem directory, in `/.terraform`. I'll note that a dot file in the root of your filesystem is a rather unusual place to keep a local filesystem mirror, but I'll use that path here anyway since you asked about it in your question.

First, configure the filesystem mirror as you already did, *and* also configure the "direct" installation method (installing from the origin registry) to exclude those same providers:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/.terraform/providers"
    include = ["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/*"]
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/*"]
  }
}
```

The above means that for any provider in the `hashicorp` namespace on the public registry, Terraform will *only* look in `/.terraform`. For all other providers, Terraform will contact the origin registry in the usual way and try to download the provider over the network.

With that configuration in place, change your shell's current working directory to be the root directory of your configuration, which is the directory containing your root set of `.tf` files. To initialize that as a working directory, which will install all of the needed providers and external modules, run:

```
terraform init
```

Terraform will then read the configuration to learn which providers it requires, and will automatically install each of them in turn. Because of the CLI configuration above, Terraform will *not* contact the origin registry for any of the `hashicorp` namespace providers, and will instead expect them to already be present in the mirror directory. Regardless of whether each provider was found in the local filesystem mirror or directly in the origin registry, they'll all then be cached in the `.terraform/providers` subdirectory of your working directory, which is the *local cache directory*.

---

You specifically asked about preventing Terraform from accessing the origin registry at all here and so I've answered with that in mind. However, a more common request is to have Terraform contact the registry the first time it installs each provider and then cache the result locally for future installation. If *that* is what you want to achieve here then you should enable [the global provider plugin cache](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/config-file.html#provider-plugin-cache) instead.

In that case, the global cache directory becomes a secondary read-through cache for the *local* cache directory I was describing above. When installing new providers to the local cache directory, Terraform will first check the global cache directory and either copy or symlink (depending on whether your system can support symlinks) the global cache entry into the local cache directory, and thus avoid re-downloading the same package from the registry again.